# Table replication in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Need to replicate tables from Prod to Test within Bigquery. Apart from BQ export/import, please let me know if there are any replication utility/tools within Bigquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a table in BigQuery you can use several methods:

- [bq tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table)
- Transfer the entire dataset using the [transfer tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#setting_up_a_dataset_copy)
- Copy using the [BigQuery UI](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/bigquery/how-to-duplicate-a-table-in-bigquery)
- You can also query the table and write its results to a new table

Answer (score 1):

You can try these options:

**BigQuery Data Transfer Service:** 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers

**Copy Tables:**

```
bq cp source-project:dataset.table target-project:dataset.table
```

**CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS):**

```
CREATE TABLE `target-project.dataset.table` AS SELECT * FROM `source-project.dataset.table`
```

**BigQuery API Client Libraries:** 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries